# WCF Always Returns 400 for Exceptions

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I have a RESTful WCF service and I've implemented an ErrorHandler such as the following:

```
public class MyErrorHandler : IErrorHandler, IServiceBehavior
{
    // OMITTED: IServiceBehavior Members

    public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
    {
        DoSomeCustomLogging(error);
        WebOperationContext ctx = WebOperationContext.Current;
        ctx.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    }           
}
```

```
   
public class MyErrorHandlerElement : BehaviorExtensionElement
{
    protected override object CreateBehavior()
    {
        return new MyErrorHandler();
    }

    public override Type BehaviorType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(MyErrorHandler);
        }
    }
}
```

It's hooked up in my web.config like so:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="Rest">
        <webHttp />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <extensions>
    <behaviorExtensions>
      <add name ="errorHandler" type="ACME.MyErrorHandlerElement, ACME.MyErrorHandler"/>
    </behaviorExtensions>
  </extensions>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  <standardEndpoints>
    <webHttpEndpoint>
      <standardEndpoint name="" faultExceptionEnabled="false" helpEnabled="false"     automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"  />
    </webHttpEndpoint>
  </standardEndpoints>
</system.serviceModel>
```

For some reason, if my service throws an exception, 400 is returned to the client instead of 500.  Any ideas why?

Comment: your webconfig is missing, please update

Comment: in the config file, type is MyErrorHandlerElement - shouldnt it be MyErrorHandler?

Comment: Eric, in the type, the first item is the ErrorHandlerElement (I've updated my example to include it) and the second is the assembly name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the fault that gets passed in by reference, this isnt your regular webmethod call.

```
#Region "IErrorHandler Members"
Public Function HandleError(ByVal [error] As Exception) As Boolean Implements IErrorHandler.HandleError
  Console.WriteLine("HandleError called.")
  ' Returning true indicates you performed your behavior.
  Return True
End Function

' This is a trivial implementation that converts Exception to FaultException<GreetingFault>.
Public Sub ProvideFault(ByVal [error] As Exception, ByVal ver As MessageVersion, ByRef msg As Message) Implements IErrorHandler.ProvideFault
  Console.WriteLine("ProvideFault called. Converting Exception to GreetingFault....")
  Dim fe As New FaultException(Of GreetingFault)(New GreetingFault([error].Message))
  Dim fault As MessageFault = fe.CreateMessageFault()
  msg = Message.CreateMessage(ver, fault, "http://microsoft.wcf.documentation/ISampleService/SampleMethodGreetingFaultFault")
End Sub
#End Region
```

[MSDN Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.providefault.aspx)

Comment: In implementing this, I now see 200 returned when an exception is thrown in a business component called by the service method, which is not ideal either.  However, this is fine (returning 500) when the exception is thrown by the service method itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is good news and bad news.  The good news is that your code would have worked if your configuration had been right.  I'll provide a fix in a moment.  The bad news is that this solution might not be stable.  According to MSDN documentation, the [ProvidFault method is not guaranteed to execute on the same thread as the service operation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.providefault(v=vs.100).aspx), and thus accessing something like `WebOperationContext.Current` might be hit-and-miss.

That said, here is what will get you fixed:

You are not seeing the results you expect, because your configuration is wrong.  Your configuration declares the extension correctly, but it doesn't bother to declare that any endpoints should use it.  Between the two asterisk comments is a fix I inserted into your configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <!-- ****************** -->
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <errorHandler />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <!-- ****************** -->
  <extensions>
    <behaviorExtensions>
      <add name ="errorHandler" type="ACME.MyErrorHandlerElement, ACME.MyErrorHandler"/>
    </behaviorExtensions>
  </extensions>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  <standardEndpoints>
    <webHttpEndpoint>
      <standardEndpoint name="" faultExceptionEnabled="false" helpEnabled="false"     automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"  />
    </webHttpEndpoint>
  </standardEndpoints>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Another problem you might have is that your configuration has asp.net compatibility mode activated.  When that mode is enabled, I have had problems with my behaviors being installed.  Your mileage may vary.

One final thing, if despite the warning from MSDN documentation you wish to continue with your approach, then I suggest you make your IErrorHandler extension look something like this:

```
public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
{
    var faultEx = error as FaultException;
    bool isRest = version == MessageVersion.None;

    if (isRest && faultEx == null)
    {
        OutgoingWebResponseContext response = WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest) {
            response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code ensures that you don't accidentally override a status code that was explicitly set by the service operation developer.  It also allows WebFaultException errors thrown by the developer to propogate with whatever status code was assigned by the developer.